# Ionic Angular Keyboard

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm having a problem after closing the keyboard the actual size of the content is not back to normal.
I checked the logs and see no errors, I'm using a component for my enter amount input.
PS. I put the enter amount in a component because I am using it in different pages.

main.page.html - part of the code not all to long to post

```
<ion-content>
 <app-enter-amount></app-enter-amount>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
 <ion-button>Confirm</ion-button>
 <ion-button>Cancel</ion-button>
</ion-footer>
```

enter.amount.html - part of the code not all to long to post
`<ion-input type="tel" inputmode="numeric"></ion-input>`

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm expecting that after closing the keyboard the content size will back to normal.
I tried so many things I found in the internet but nothing works. My last option is to not use component and put enter amount html and functions in every pages, If I cant figure this out.
If there is something missing in my question or you guys want to know please let me know, Thank you very much.

Comment: I'll just add I'm using android device here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after of so many hours of debugging I just found out that this css style `position:fixed` in my input is the reason, its like having some conflict when the keyboard pops up & out.

Comment: I want to explain more but I don't have that much idea why this is an issue `position:fixed` in my ion-input but after removing it solves my problem.